# Ajax and jQuery handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I study Ajax and I have the problem.

For example, my markup is

```
<div id='ajax-container'>
  ..
  <div class='some-class-with-handler'>
    ..
  </div>
  ..
</div>
```

And I have the onClick-handler for **.some-class-with-handler**-block

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  ..
  $('.some-class-with-handler').click(function(){
    ..
  });
  ..
}
```

Then Ajax overload everything in **#ajax-container**-block, but **.some-class-with-handler**-block is still included in the new content of **#ajax-container**-block. At the same time onClick handler isn't bind to the new **.some-class-with-handler**-block. How can I rebuild this binding?

Comment: Post how are you inserting the ajax response into `#ajax-container-block`

Comment: Delegate your event http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two choices:

1. Use `jQuery.live`: http://api.jquery.com/live/

   *Update*: According to the doc, `live` is deprecated as of 1.7. You can use this syntax mentioned in the above doc:

   ```
   $( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
   $( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
   $( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
   ```
2. Rebind the `click` handler after AJAX

   ```
   var someClassClickHandler = function(){
       ..
   };

   $('.some-class-with-handler').click(someClassClickHandler);

   $.ajax({
       success: function () {
           $('.some-class-with-handler').click(someClassClickHandler);
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: I was literally typing this. T_T

Comment: Don't use `.live()`, it has been long deprecated. Use event delegation instead.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the new `.some-class-with-handler` is a new element and you can't bind new elements this way. Change your handler this way -

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  ..
  $(document).on('click','.some-class-with-handler', function(){
    ..
  });
  ..
}
```